# YACC Bison GLR parser won't split on a reduce/reduce conflict

Tags: parsing, bison, yacc

I prepare a parser in GNU Bison in GLR mode. It have a reduce/reduce conflict, therefore I turn on GLR mode, expecting it will then split the parser and proceed to discover which parses work. But it doesn't do:

```
%{
#include <stdio.h>
int yylex ();
void yyerror(const char* msg);
%}

%glr-parser
%start start
%%

/* With input:
  ({}=0)

   the parser ought to split.
*/

start: AssignmentExpressionNB '\n';

AssignmentExpressionNB:
    PrimaryExpressionNB
    | PrimaryExpressionNB '=' AssignmentExpression
    ;
AssignmentExpression:
      PrimaryExpression /* This one will be rejected fast */
    | ObjectAssignmentPattern '=' AssignmentExpression /* This must kept. */
    | PrimaryExpression '=' AssignmentExpression /* This must also kept. */
    ;

PrimaryExpressionNB: 
      '0'
    | '(' PrimaryExpression ')' { $$ = $2; }
    ;
PrimaryExpression:
      '{' '}' { $$= 42; }
    | PrimaryExpressionNB { $$ = $1; }
    ;

ObjectAssignmentPattern: '{' '}';

%%
void yyerror(const char* msg) { printf("%s\n", msg); }
int yylex () {
    int c;
    while ((c = getchar ()) == ' ' || c == '\t');
    return c == EOF ? 0 : c;
}
int main (int argc, char** argv) {
    yydebug=1;
    return yyparse();
}
```

Unfortunately it does not split, but simply reduces by AssignmentExpression's first alternative the {} to a PrimaryExpression and then has a syntax error:

```
Starting parse
Entering state 0
Reading a token
({}=0)
Next token is token '(' ()
Shifting token '(' ()
Entering state 2
Reading a token
Next token is token '{' ()
Shifting token '{' ()
Entering state 6
Reading a token
Next token is token '}' ()
Shifting token '}' ()
Entering state 12
Reducing stack 0 by rule 9 (line 34):
   $1 = token '{' ()
   $2 = token '}' ()
-> $$ = nterm PrimaryExpression ()
Entering state 8
Reading a token
Next token is token '=' ()
syntax error
Error: popping nterm PrimaryExpression ()
Error: popping token '(' ()
Cleanup: discarding lookahead token '=' ()
```

I thought the GNU Bison should split parsing now to determine which works (and if there are multiple successful parse, then to let me choose which.)

There is a way to get the alternatives?

Answer (score 0):

That example is unambiguously a syntax error; there is nothing which GLR can do to change that.

The only place in your grammar where parentheses are allowed is

```
PrimaryExpressionNB: '(' PrimaryExpression ')' { $$ = $2; }
```

so what is enclosed in parentheses must be a `PrimaryExpression`. But the `=` is only accepted in productions deriving from `AssignmentExpression`, and `PrimaryExpression` cannot derive `AssignmentExpression`. So an `=` cannot appear in a `PrimaryExpression`, and therefore `{}=0` is not a `PrimaryExpression`. Thus `({}=0)` cannot be derived from `PrimaryExpressionNB`, and the input is invalid.

`{}=0` is also invalid, because the start symbol only derives `AssignmentExpressionNB`, which must start with a `PrimaryExpressionNB`, and `{}` is not a `PrimaryExpressionNB`. I assume that's deliberate and that `NB` stands for something like "No Brace".

`({})=0` can be an `AssignmentExpressionNB`, since `({})` is a `PrimaryExpressionNB`. But that doesn't encounter the reduce/reduce conflict, also because `AssignmentExpressionNB` can't start with `PrimaryExpression`, and thus there is only one usable production which includes `=`.

To reach the reduce/reduce conflict, then, we need `({})={}=0`, in which the `{}=0` must be derived from `PrimaryExpression`. Now, however, the grammar reveals itself to be actually ambiguous, not just non-deterministic.

The key non-terminal is:

```
AssignmentExpression:
      PrimaryExpression /* This one will be rejected fast */
    | ObjectAssignmentPattern '=' AssignmentExpression /* This must kept. */
    | PrimaryExpression '=' AssignmentExpression /* This must also kept. */
```

The first comment there is incorrect. With or without GLR, a bottom-up parser does not need to reject the first production "fast". It can leave the option open until the `=` is encountered (or not). If an `=` is not encountered, then the first production is the only possibility, and `AssignmentExpression` is immediately reduced. But if there is an `=`, one of the other two productions for `AssignmentExpression` must be used. The problem is that absolutely nothing distinguishes the other two productions, and in this context either could be a valid parse. The Bison GLR parser does not tolerate actual ambiguity, so it throws an ambiguity error at that point (not a syntax error).